# jquery with android

Tags: jquery, android

how to use jquery components with android

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery on iPhone/Android/BlackBerry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921130/jquery-on-iphone-android-blackberry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/ help?

Comment: Are you just starting with JQuery? If you are, then it will help if you work with standard jQuery samples to get started before moving to jquery mobile. See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/